# Removing an item from NSPasteboard

Tags: cocoa, copy-paste, nspasteboard

Target: Mac OS X 10.7+, Xcode 4.3.x

Core need: when dragging/pasting, allow me to process one type of item, pass along the rest to the superclass.

I've got a subclass of `NSTextView` with a performDragOperation method.  What I'd like to do is intercept all file drops to do extra things with, then allow any other items to get passed along to the superclass (`NSTextView`) with a call to `[super performDragOperation]`

I don't see a way to remove one item from a pasteboard. It appears that I only have 2 choices:

1. Handle inserting all of the pasteboard items into my textView myself.
2. Cache the items, clear the pasteboard, then insert them back in before passing them up the chain (I've tried this option without success, but I may know why it's breaking).

Did I miss a #3 option? If not, which of #1 or #2 would you suggest?